# How to create django app programmatically using call_command

Tags: python, django

In my project current scenario i am required to create app programmatically.
What i have done so far, the steps are listed below.

1 - I have created a test app which is just simple text field crud.
[image: This is just Test app model]

2 - In Testapp model i am using post_save.connect method to run some custom app generation code.

```
def model_created_or_updated(sender, **kwargs):
the_instance = kwargs['instance']
if kwargs['created']:
    app_name = ''.join(the_instance.test_title.lower().split())
    generate_app(app_name)
    generate_app_model(app_name)
    generate_settings(app_name)
    create_migration(app_name)

post_save.connect(model_created_or_updated, sender=TestApp)
```

3 - Now the first generate_app method create app (see below), Below function will created the app

```
def generate_app(self):
management.call_command('startapp', self)
```

4 - After that i have generate_app_model, I have programmatically write the newly created app model to add some custom fields in it.

```
def generate_app_model(self):
app_name = self

try:
    model_file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, app_name + '/models.py'), 'r+')
except IOError:
    print("An error was found. Either path is incorrect or file doesn't exist!")
finally:
    class_name = str(app_name).capitalize()
    title_field = app_name + '_title'
    file_field = app_name + '_file'
    timestamp_field = app_name + '_timestamp'
    line1 = 'from django.db import models \n\n'
    line2 = 'class ' + class_name + '(models.Model): \n\n'
    line3 = '\t' + title_field + ' = models.CharField(max_length=200) \n'
    line4 = '\t' + file_field + ' = models.FileField(upload_to="uploads/' + app_name + '/") \n'
    line5 = '\t' + timestamp_field + ' = models.DateTimeField("date published") \n\n'
    line6 = '\tdef __str__(self): \n'
    line7 = '\t\treturn self.'+title_field+' \n'
    model_file_.writelines([line1, line2, line3, line4, line5, line6, line7])
    model_file_.close()
```

5 - After that i have generate_settings function which import the settings_local.py file at the bottom of settings.py

```
def generate_settings(self):
app_name = self
# finale_app_name = str(app_name)+'.apps.'+str(app_name).capitalize()+'Config'
settings.INSTALLED_APPS += (app_name,)
# apps.app_configs = OrderedDict()
# apps.apps_ready = apps.models_ready = apps.loading = apps.ready = False
# apps.clear_cache()
# apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
try:
    local_setting_file_ = open(os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR, 'virtualcases/settings_local.py'), 'r+')
except IOError:
    print("An error was found. Either path is incorrect or file doesn't exist!")
finally:
    # final_settings = settings.INSTALLED_APPS
    installed_apps = "from .settings import *\nINSTALLED_APPS += ['" + str(app_name) + "']"
    local_setting_file_.writelines(installed_apps)
    local_setting_file_.close()
```

The output of settings_local.py is below

```
from .settings import *
INSTALLED_APPS += ['movie']
```

6 - Now the final move is creating problems for me. Last function is create_migration.

```
def create_migration(self):
app_name = self
apps.app_configs = OrderedDict()
apps.apps_ready = apps.models_ready = apps.loading = apps.ready = False
apps.clear_cache()
apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
management.call_command('makemigrations', app_name)
management.call_command('migrate', app_name)
```

When makemigrations command run it will create the 0001_initial.py migration file in specified app folder.
But when migrate command run it says no migration to apply.
Because app name not listed in settings.py file but i have write another settings_local.py file and this migrate command did not import from settings_local.py file.

Below is he output from my terminal.
[image: From Terminal Output]

Here is my settings.py file code which import the settings_local.py file

```
try:
    from .settings_local import *
except ImportError:
    pass
```

I would be very appreciated if any django professional help me in django way.
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain the use case a bit here? Why do you need to do this as opposed to creating an instance 
of a model for example?

Comment: @Sayse I have already an app with same above model code registered in my django project. And i want to create another same duplicate app from django admin dashboard.

Comment: That's kind of my point, what would be different?  Are you trying to create a multi-tenancy solution? I'm struggling to see how this could be maintained on a db or deployment level which leads me to believe there's probably a different approach to take to whatever it is you're trying to achieve

Comment: @Sayse I do not consider any db or deployment scenarios in my mind right now, because there will be hardly only 5 to 6 apps created from django administration.
And each app is represent a different folder in which microscopic slides will be resides. 
I am running app using wsgi and i want to implement this solution totally command free for client.
So client can easily create an app from backend and after that he will see the cases from his own app.

Comment: honestly, unless you are doing it for a class assignment, this seems like a bad idea.  esp creating generated code via `write` w tabs in it.  least you should consider is a template system like Jinja2 and externalizing templates to files with a lot of params/snippets stored in json or yaml, not in your code. I do a lot of dynamic code and code generation myself and I expect you will find this very brittle and limited in practice, past proof-of-concept.   you can also look at something like CookieCutter or better yet an equivalent template-based generator with if/while... flow control.

Comment: @JLPeyret Thansks i will look forward to your advice.